# Spring WebFlux - Integrating with CompletionStages

Tags: java, spring-webflux, completion-stage

So far I have been implementing Async non-blocking IO with `CompletionStages` but I am now attempting to build a `Spring-Webflux` service while attempting to reuse existing code.

I have an existing HttpClient that returns a `CompletionStage` and as part of my logic I need to perform 3 HTTP calls, each dependent on the last. I know that I can convert a `CompletionStage` to a `Mono` using `Mono.fromCompetionStage`, but I am wondering how I can fluently compose the calls so that my Rest Controller can return a Mono representing all the operations in sequence.

I know that if I was just using `CompletionStages` I could  chain them using `thenCompose`:

```
return client.firstCall()
             .thenCompose(client::secondCall)
             .thenCompose(client::thirdCall)
```

Any idea what the best way to achieve this would be with using a `Mono`. If the answer is to take the resulting `CompletionStage` from the above code and do `Mono.fromCompletionStage` I see little point, as `Spring-Weblfux` supports returning `CompletionStages`.